# Canvas toBlob quality

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

Our app takes canvas content and then display it as thumbnail with max-height of 150px

canvas can be as large as the monitor, for now lets pick 2560x1440

If converting to webp,

is there an equation to get quality number that roughly preserve image quality ? , maybe

```
targetHeight = 150
originalHeight = 1440

quality = targetHeight / originalHeight 
// 150px / 1440px ~ 0.1 ?

canvas.toBlob((blob) => {

    const currentScreenshot = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

}, "image/webp", quality);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can **only** set `quality` value by defining mime type with `image/jpeg` or `image/webp`.

The default values are **0.92** & **0.80** respectively. Other values are ignored.

Please refer to this [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Parameters) for `HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()` details.

Comment: yes, the question is how to get quality value when resizing down?